# How to click on a particular row of webtable in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have web table which has 95 div lines in web table.I want to click on each one of them but am unable to do it.The x path of 1st line,2nd one and the last one am pasting here.Data is not written in rows and columns so that's why am getting confused.Can anyone tell me how to deal with the x paths which am pasting below:

1. `css=div.x-grid3-cell-inner.x-grid3-col-title-col1`
2. `//div[@id='ext-gen1013']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div`
3. `//div[@id='ext-gen1013']/div[95]/table/tbody/tr/td/div..`

1st one is css selector and from 2nd one onwards i have x paths with div[x] value changing rest all are same.

1st HTML mark up table

```
<div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-first" style="width:250px;">
<table class="x-grid3-row-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:250px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-title-col1 x-grid3-cell-first " tabindex="0" style="width: 248px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-title-col1" unselectable="on">DFSAFSDHL</div>
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-title-col2 x-grid3-cell-last " tabindex="0" style="width: 48px;display: none; ">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

2nd div class html mark up table.

```
<div class="x-grid3-row " style="width:250px;">
<table class="x-grid3-row-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:250px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-title-col1 x-grid3-cell-first " tabindex="0" style="width: 248px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-title-col1" unselectable="on">DIR</div>
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-title-col2 x-grid3-cell-last " tabindex="0" style="width: 48px;display: none; ">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-title-col2" unselectable="on">Distribution</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML markup for the table

Comment: Provide HTML please with your table.

Comment: I pasted HTML code for first two div classes.If need anything else i would be glad to provide.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also provide html markup of the parent element for `<div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-first" style="width:250px;">`?

Comment: Thanks mfsi_sitamj, i got the solution.Actullay my all table ids were same and number of tables were 96 so selenium webdriver was showing error unable to locate webelement as it was getting confused.So i changed the xpath. Original xpath was //div[@id='ext-gen777']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div       and  i changed xpath as  //table[@class='x-grid3-row-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div. I edited xpath since all div ids were dynamic,so i edited with table value and though table values are same for 96 tables but by using table class value i returned all elements in list,got size and performed click.